# Reactive way to read and parse file from resources using WebFlux?

Tags: json, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I wonder what is the correct way to read, parse and serve a file from resources.

Currently, I do something like this:

```
fun getFile(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    val parsedJson =
        objectMapper.readValue(readFile("fileName.json"), JsonModel::class.java)

    // modify parsed json

    return ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(parsedJson)
}

private fun readFile(fileName: String) =
    DefaultResourceLoader()
        .getResource(fileName)
        .inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
```

I've noticed [JsonObjectDecoder](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/json/JsonObjectDecoder.html) class in Netty, but I don't know if can be applied to my use case.

What is the reactive way to do read/parse resource file then?

Comment: All i/o operations are blocking. The reading of the file should by wrapped in a `Mono#fromCallable` and placed on its own `scheduler` thats bounded to avoid thread starvation. You can read more about blocking calls here https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After expanding @vins answer, I've came to following solution:

```
Jackson2JsonDecoder()
    .decodeToMono(
        DataBufferUtils.read(
            DefaultResourceLoader()
                .getResource("$fileName.json"),
            DefaultDataBufferFactory(),
            4096
        ),
        ResolvableType.forClass(JsonModel::class.java), null, null
    )
    .map { it as JsonModel }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at `Flux.using` [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference) for file read.

As you are using Spring framework, You can also take a look at the `DataBufferUtils`.

This `DataBufferUtils` uses `AsynchronousFileChannel` to read the file and it also internally uses `Flux.using` to release the file once the file is read / cancelled by the subscriber.

```
@Value("classpath:somefile.json")
private Resource resource;


@GetMapping("/resource")
public Flux<DataBuffer> serve(){
   return DataBufferUtils.read(
            this.resource,
            new DefaultDataBufferFactory(),
            4096
    );
}
```