# Unable to read classpath resource file in non-blocking way inside docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to load a JSON file **sample.json** from `src/main/resources` directory.

I have to map that json to a Java Object. And my application is reactive, I am using Spring webflux.

I have followed [Simon's Blog](https://simonbasle.github.io/2017/10/file-reading-in-reactor/) to come up with this:

```
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<>() {
      @Override
      public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(p.getValueAsString());
      }
    });

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);


    return Flux.using(() -> Files.lines(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("sample.json").toURI())),
        Flux::fromStream,
        BaseStream::close
    )
        .collectList()
        .map(lines -> String.join("\n", lines))
        .map(jsonContent -> {
          try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(jsonContent, MyPojo.class);
          } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }
        })
        .map(MyPojo::getValues());
```

This works fine in local but fails when running inside a docker container. (I am using gradle build to build the jar file and then build the docker image from it)

Part of the error stacktrace:

> java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
> at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:169) ~[jdk.zipfs:na]
> Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:

Comment: Check that the wnated resource is your classpath inside the Docker container. Maybe you have to add it in your Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Comment: Simon's solution is also using blocking I/O, so if you have no benefit from using Flux here, then you can just read the file in regular blocking way using inputstream and offload the work to an elastic Scheduler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactive way to read and parse file from resources using WebFlux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139186/reactive-way-to-read-and-parse-file-from-resources-using-webflux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running the docker image, you are trying to access the file from inside a Jar. And it seems that passing a resource URI directly to `Paths.get` won't work.

You can refer to the following stackoverflow discussions regarding the same:

1. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713119/java-nio-file-path-for-a-classpath-resource#answer-15718001)
2. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746667/java-nio-file-filesystemnotfoundexception-when-getting-file-from-resources-folde/29747012)
3. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605666/java-access-files-in-jar-causes-java-nio-file-filesystemnotfoundexception)

I think you should take a look at [this class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/json/Jackson2JsonDecoder.html) of Spring which decodes a byte stream into JSON and convert to Object's with Jackson 2.9, leveraging non-blocking parsing.

This code should serve your needs:

First get reference to the `Resource` in Spring's way

```
  @Value("classpath:/sample.json")
  Resource sampleFile;
```

Then do this:

```
return new Jackson2JsonDecoder()
        .decodeToMono(
            DataBufferUtils.read(sampleFile, new DefaultDataBufferFactory(), 4096),
            ResolvableType.forClass(MyPojo.class),
            null,
            null)
        .map(object -> (MyPojo) object)
        .map(MyPojo::getValues)
```

In this way, you can read the file in a non-blocking manner using `DataBufferUtils.read` and also map the json to your POJO.